# how is it possible to use spray and akka without blocking until result is estimated?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray, chain

This question is more about architecture than anything else.
I just started building a Rest API with akka. Currently I use play for doing the necessary routing. The problem with play is that I have my entry point for akka within my controller, so there is always one actor that has to wait all the time until my business logic calculates a suitable response. 
Now I came across spray and it looks like there is nearly the same problem with it. (spray-routing)

What I`m trying to achieve is that I have an entry point that receives a HTTPRequest, then the request is handled by my actor system and at the end of this system there is an actor which sends the priviously calculated response back to the requesting client.

Actually I cant figure out how to chain actors without waiting for an end result. What I want is a "START" - Actor receiving a Request and one at the end sending back the response.

I hope i wrote it so that someone understands what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you usually do is "completing with a Future". This means your inner route looks roughly like this `complete(calculationActor ? DoCalculation(...))`. There should be several examples around the web showing how that works exactly.

Comment: See e.g. this post which shows this pattern: http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2013/06/scala-web-apis-up-and-running-with-spray-and-akka/

Comment: Spray pretty much does what you described. Here is a template: https://typesafe.com/activator/template/spray-actor-per-request

Comment: Ok.. Thank you guys. I think I got it. I will play around with these tools you showed me. I`m sure I will be able to answer my own question afterwards. thx